# c++11 local static member variable destruction order for shared_ptr objects

Tags: c++11, global-variables, shared-ptr, lifetime, static-variables

I've been struggling with a destructor call order which I cannot really understand.

Say we have the following definitions:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class DummyClass {
    std::string name;
public:
    DummyClass(std::string name) : name(name) { std::cout << "DummyClass(" << name << ")" << std::endl; }
    ~DummyClass() { std::cout << "~DummyClass(" << name << ")" << std::endl; }
};


class TestClass {
private:

    static DummyClass dummy;

    static DummyClass& objects() {
        static DummyClass dummy("inner");
        return dummy;
    }
public:
    TestClass() {
        std::cout << "TestClass" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "TestClass Objects is: " << &objects() << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~TestClass() {
        std::cout << "~TestClass Objects is: " << &objects() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "~TestClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

DummyClass TestClass::dummy("outer");
```

Now, If I instantiate the `TestClass` as follows:

```
TestClass *mTest = nullptr;

int main() {
    mTest = new TestClass(); delete mTest;
    return 0;
}
```

The output obtained is the one I would expect:

```
DummyClass(outer)
TestClass
DummyClass(inner)
TestClass Objects is: 0x....
~TestClass Objects is: 0x....
~TestClass
~DummyClass(inner)
~DummyClass(outer)
```

But, now, if I use a shared_ptr for mTest, like:

```
std::shared_ptr<TestClass> mTest;

int main() {
    mTest = std::make_shared<TestClass>();
    return 0;
}
```

the output produced is:

```
DummyClass(outer)
TestClass
DummyClass(inner)
TestClass Objects is: 0x....
~DummyClass(inner)
~TestClass Objects is: 0x....
~TestClass
~DummyClass(outer)
```

Can someone explain why is the DummyClass inner object being destroyed before the end of the TestClass object destructor, in this particular case?
I found consistent behavior for gcc 5.2.0 using -std=gnu++11 and clang 3.8.0 with -std=c++11 but could not find any particular documentation citing this example.

**Edit:** To clarify: all of the code above was written in the same translation unit (*.cpp file) in the presented order. It is a simplification of a usage case where I have a header only class definition which must hold a static list of `this` pointers to derived class objects. These pointers are added via ctor and removed when the dtor is reached. The problem is triggered when destroying the last object. The list is kept inside a static method and accessed through it to achieve the *header only* goal.

Comment: Are the definitions `DummyClass TestClass::dummy("outer");` and `std::shared_ptr<TestClass> mTest;` in the same translation unit (*.cpp file) or different ones? If the same one, which one is first?

Comment: Everything, in this example, is in the same translation unit. The order is as presented, so `DummyClass TestClass::dummy("outer");` comes before `std::shared_ptr<TestClass> mTest;`

Answer (score 1):

The rules for all objects with static storage duration (namespace members, static class members, and `static` objects in function definitions) are:

- If the entire initialization can be considered a constant expression, that initialization happens before anything else. (Doesn't apply to anything in your examples.) Otherwise,
- Namespace members and static class members are guaranteed to begin initialization at some point before any function in the same translation unit is called.  (In most implementations, if we ignore dynamic library loading, all of these happen before `main` begins.  In your examples, since `main` is in the same TU, we know they happen before `main`.)
- Namespace members and static class members defined in the same TU begin their initializations in the order of their definitions.
- For namespace members and static class members defined in different TUs, there is no guarantee on order of initialization!
- Static objects defined inside a function begin their initialization the first time program control reaches the definition (if ever).
- When `main` returns or `std::exit` is called, all objects with static storage duration are destroyed in order opposite to when each **completed** its initialization.

So in your second example:

1. Initialization of `TestClass::dummy` begins. First a temporary `std::string` is created, and then `DummyClass::DummyClass(std::string)` is called.
2. The `DummyClass` constructor does a `std::string` copy, then outputs `"DummyClass(outer)\n"`. The temporary `std::string` is destroyed. Initialization of `TestClass::dummy` is complete.
3. Initialization of `::mTest` begins. This calls `std::shared_ptr<TestClass>::shared_ptr()`.
4. The `shared_ptr` constructor sets up the smart pointer to be null. Initialization of `::mTest` is complete.
5. `main` begins.
6. The `std::make_shared` call ends up creating a `TestClass` object, calling `TestClass::TestClass()`. This constructor first prints `"TestClass\n"`, then calls `TestClass::objects()`.
7. Inside `TestClass::objects()`, initialization of local object `dummy` begins. Again a temporary `std::string` is created, and `DummyClass::DummyClass(std::string)` is called.
8. The `DummyClass` constructor does a `std::string` copy, then outputs `"DummyClass(inner)\n"`. The temporary `std::string` is destroyed. Initialization of `objects`' `dummy` is complete.
9. `TestClass::TestClass()` continues, printing `"TestClass Objects is: 0x`...`\n"`.  Initialization of the dynamic `TestClass` object is complete.
10. Back in `main`, the `make_shared` function returns a temporary `std::shared_ptr<TestClass>`. A move assignment moves from the returned temporary to `::mTest`, then the temporary is destroyed. Note that although the `TestClass` object is associated with `::mTest`, it has dynamic storage duration, not static storage duration, so the above rules do not apply to it.
11. `main` returns. C++ begins destroying objects with static storage duration.
12. The last static object to finish initialization was the `dummy` local of `TestClass::objects()` at step 8 above, so it is destroyed first. Its destructor body outputs `"~DummyClass(inner)\n"`.
13. The next object to finish initializing was `::mTest` in step 4 above, so its destruction begins next. The `~shared_ptr` destructor ends up destroying the owned dynamic `TestClass` object.
14. The `TestClass::~TestClass()` destructor body first calls `TestClass::objects()`.
15. In `TestClass::objects()`, we encounter the definition of an already destroyed function-local static, which is Undefined Behavior!  Apparently though, your implementation does nothing but return a reference to the storage that formerly contained `dummy`, and it's probably a good thing you didn't do anything with it other than take the address.
16. `TestClass::~TestClass()` continues, outputting `"~TestClass Objects is: 0x`...`\n"` and then `"~TestClass\n"`.
17. The `~shared_ptr` destructor for `::mTest` deallocates associated memory and completes.
18. Finally, the first static object to finish initialization was `TestClass::dummy`, in step 2 above, so it is destroyed last. The `DummyClass::~DummyClass` destructor body outputs `"~DummyClass\n"`. The program is finished.

So the big difference between your two examples is the fact that the `TestClass` destruction gets delayed until the `shared_ptr` is destroyed - it doesn't really matter when in the scheme of things the `TestClass` was created. Since the `shared_ptr` was created before the "inner" `DummyClass` in the second example, its destruction happens after the "inner" object is gone, causing that Undefined Behavior.

If this is a simplification of an actual issue you ran into and need to fix, you might try adding something like

```
class TestClass {
    // ...
public:
    class ForceInit {
        ForceInit() { TestClass::objects(); }
    };
    // ...
};

// ...
TestClass::ForceInit force_init_before_mTest;
std::shared_ptr<TestClass> mTest;
```

Comment: Indeed, this is just a simplification of a rather more complex case: 
I have a header only class definition which must hold a static list of `this` pointers to derived class objects. These pointers are added via ctor and removed when the dtor is reached. The problem is, obviously, when destroying the last object.
The list is kept inside a static method and accessed through it

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to shared_ptr but to the order of destruction of global variables in modules (cc files). The spec states that the order is undefined so you can not assume that static inner object will be destroyed after or before another global object. If you need to have a consistent order of destruction I advise that you take care of it explicitly.